# rotating dynamic images through jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I've been try to animate of queue of images through jQuery. For some reason it is ignoring my jquery function. Images will be load to the document dynamically through JSON data. So far I was able load the images and push each div as the next image load, It's not smooth. Container div is call #stream. Each image is under div class call status.

i'm try to move every image to left 270px after it is loaded(loop).

template for the images

```
 queue.next(function(status, step) {
 var div = document.createElement('div');

 // create DOM element
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.className = 'status';
 var photo = status.images.standard_resolution.url; 
 div.innerHTML = '<img src="'+photo+'"/>';

 // add div to the top of the stream element (each new status is newer)
 document.getElementById('stream').insertBefore(div,     document.getElementById('stream').firstChild);

setTimeout(step, 1000);

});
```

jQuery I'm trying to work with

```
  $(window).ready(function(){
    animateTheBox();
   }); 

 function animateTheBox() {
    $(".status").animate({"left": "+=270px"},"slow");
  }
```

any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling your animate function on the doument ready event

```
  $(window).ready(function(){
    animateTheBox();
   });
```

You should call `animateTheBox();` function after loading the image.

ie in the `step` function mentioned in the `setTimeout(step, 1000);` call

Comment: you mean like this $(window).load(function()? I tried that but, it is ignoring my whole jQuery functions. Thank you

Comment: No. Try to add animateTheBox(); after setTimeout(step, 1000);

Comment: Ok. you kind of gave me good idea. I tried moving the call right after setTimeout, then I tried for before the setfTimeout. still ignored it.  I'm thinking I just need to call within setTimeout.